# tile image along right side of activity

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there a way for me to tile an image along the right side of an activity view? The image i have is small and square.

i know you can tile the entire activity view like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/actual_pattern_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

but is there a way to restrain it? to make it just tile one image under the other along the right side?

i know i can do something like this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
```

and just keep increasing the margin as i add another imageView below. my only fear with this approach is when scoll-bars come into picture. this is clearly a very static approach...

just a heads up - very new to android development...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the width of your tile, you can create a bitMap whose width is the width of your tile, and whose height is the height of the full view.  Then place this view on the right side of your activity view.

It would be easiest if your view had a relative layout that filled your view, and you had your bitmap align with the the right of the relative layout like this:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```